# Windows 7 freezes on connecting second time to same wifi network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, freeze

I am using Lenovo - y470, which comes with windows 7 home premium. I can connect to my wifi network and there is no issue in that. But the problem comes if the network get disconnected and i again try to connect to same wifi network. As soon as i click on `connect` my system freezes, and i can not even press ctrl+ alt+ del . The only think i am allowed to do at that time is press and hold power button to shut down the system and restart it again.

Please tell me how to resolve this issue. Please let me know if some more information is required.

OS: Windows 7
Router: Netgear n-150

Answer (score 0):

In general a freezing system would indicate either a hardware or a driver fault. So the first thing to do is update your wifi driver.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the automatic drivers from when you plug in the device? They can be inferior to the drivers you use from a CD or from the manufacturer site.

Download the drivers from the manufacturer site for your model, then once you've got those, uninstall the drivers in Device Manager.

You can access Device Manager using Windows Key + X and selecting it from the list. Then select your wireless adapter, uninstall it.

Install your new drivers for your adapter and they should hopefully work better. If yours is an older device it may not be optimised for Windows 7, or vice versa it may be optimised for more recent versions of Windows.

I know that faulty drivers still cause an issue with Network Connections and with View wireless networks in Windows 10.